# How to complement missing dates after groupby for each group in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

My goal is to complement the missing date entries per `project_id` with 0 in the `data` row.

For example

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'project_id': ['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
    'timestamp': ['2018-01-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-03-01', '2018-06-01'], 
    'data': [100, 28, 45, 64, 55]})
```

which is

```
  project_id   timestamp  data
0          A  2018-01-01   100
1          A  2018-03-01    28
2          A  2018-04-01    45
3          B  2018-03-01    64
4          B  2018-06-01    55
```

shall become

```
  project_id   timestamp  data
0          A  2018-01-01   100
1          A  2018-02-01     0
2          A  2018-03-01    28
3          A  2018-04-01    45
4          B  2018-03-01    64
5          B  2018-04-01     0
6          B  2018-05-01     0
7          B  2018-06-01    55
```

where indices 1, 5, and 6 are added.

My current approach :

```
df.groupby('project_id').apply(lambda x: x[['timestamp', 'data']].set_index('timestamp').asfreq('M', how='start', fill_value=0))
```

is obviously wrong, because it sets everything to `0` and resampled not the first date of a month but the last one - although I thought this should be handled by `how`.

How do I expand/complement missing `datetime` entries after `groupby` to get a continuous time series for each group?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are close:

```
df.timestamp = pd.to_datetime(df.timestamp)

# notice 'MS'
new_df = df.groupby('project_id').apply(lambda x: x[['timestamp', 'data']]
                                                    .set_index('timestamp').asfreq('MS'))

new_df.data = df.set_index(['project_id', 'timestamp']).data
df = new_df.fillna(0).reset_index()
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`groupby`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) in combination with [`pandas.Grouper`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Grouper.html):

```
df_new = pd.concat([
    d for n, d in df.set_index('timestamp').groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS'))
])

df_new = df_new.sort_values('project_id').reset_index()
```

**Output**

```
print(df_new)
   timestamp project_id   data
0 2018-01-01          A  100.0
1 2018-02-01          A    0.0
2 2018-03-01          A   28.0
3 2018-04-01          A   45.0
4 2018-03-01          B   64.0
5 2018-04-01          B    0.0
6 2018-05-01          B    0.0
7 2018-06-01          B   55.0
```